# stream to excel without saving

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am creating excel and filling values into it. i am using EPPlus.
I can save it using filestream and open it.
but i want to open it without saving. 
I thought we can use memorystream in some way to generate the excel directly.
Please guide.

```
try
        {
            MemoryStream newFile = new MemoryStream();
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {


                // Add Data Collection worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet dataWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");


                dataWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = " My Text";
                dataWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Size = 14;
                dataWorksheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = BALGlobalVariables.cocName;
                dataWorksheet.Cells[5, 1].Value = "IR From Date :";
                dataWorksheet.Cells[6, 1].Value = "IR To Date : ";
                dataWorksheet.Cells[5, 6].Value = "From Date :";
                dataWorksheet.Cells[6, 6].Value = "To Date : ";

                dataWorksheet.Cells[5, 2].Value = fromDate;
                dataWorksheet.Cells[6, 2].Value = toDate;
                dataWorksheet.Cells[5, 7].Value = invFromDate;
                dataWorksheet.Cells[6, 7].Value = invFromDate;




                // Template specific excel generation goes in here
                FillPurchaseExcelData(ref dataWorksheet, masterTable, subTable);

                // save package
                package.Save();

            }

            byte[] fileContent = newFile.ToArray();
#if DEBUG
            string tempName = "MTemp.xlsx";
            string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + @"\" + tempName;

            //Write the stream data of workbook to the root directory
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);

            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempFileName);
```

Comment: `open it without saving` I don't know what that means.

Comment: I wanted to show the excel as Book1 instead of somefilename.xlsx, and to show message to save the generated excel before closing.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate excel file and choose not to save it, but Excel can't open files that are not saved on disk (it becomes a 'file' when it's on disk), so in short - you have to save document in order to open it in Excel.

If you're concerned about storing data on hard drive, as an alternative you could create a data source on a medium you trust, and then create an xslx that would instruct Excel to consume that data source when opening worksheet (instead of creating a file pre-filled with data). But this is a whole other story...

Comment: Thanks for reply veljkoz.. I wanted to show the excel as Book1 instead of somefilename.xlsx, and to show message to save the generated excel before closing. how do i save my excel formatted values in data source ?